# Sometimes i get server error code -1 on request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Nodejs server with `Express`, `Sequelize` and `Postgresl`. When i request to server, sometimes get `-1` error code in the server. But it isn't caught Express Error Handling(http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). What is the `-1` error code? My client server is Angular.

Comment: This is network error. Maybe occur due timeout.

Comment: Post your code.